# get UTC time of every video frame using ffmepg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtp

I just read a RTSP stream from my IP Camera using FFMPEG. I need to display UTC time of every frame and video frame synchronously. The player GUI I created by Qt.

At very first, I just use libVLC to implement my requirement. Then, I just found out that LibVLC cannot get UTC timestamp of every frame(https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=128403), So I was out to move from libvlc to ffmepg.   I code a Demo read RTSP using ffmpeg library and print the presentation time of every frame . but I find the presentation time is relative , It start from zero up to end.  How I can convert the time to UTC?  RTP Packet's timestamp is relative, It only need RTCP sender report's absolute timestamp to calculate the UTC. How can I get the UTC time of every frame using FFMPEG??

In FFPMEG  every frame has own pts in struct AVFrame, the pts just copied from AVPacket, the struct AVStream has time_base this field,  UTC time is equal to time_base*pts ?

my code snippet  as follows:

```
//SDL End----------------------
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet)>=0){


    if(packet->stream_index==videoindex){
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, packet);
        if(ret < 0){
            printf("Decode Error.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        int64_t utc = packet->pts * av_q2d(pStream->time_base);
        printf("UTC is :%I64d\n", utc);
```

What's Wrong?

Comment: is there a timestamp for every frame? I suspect you will have to infer from the pts

Comment: @GradyPlayer How Can I infer the UTC from PTS??   I just google  convert PTS to UTC , and cannot find anything about it.  It is not  the UTC = gettimeofday() + packet->pts * av_q2d(pStream->time_base). if it is, It is too speculative， because the return value of gettimeofday() is local

Comment: Can you infer that the creation date of the file is the creation date of the video?

Comment: i don't know what is available at the rtsp or the rtp level, but at the level of the video, each frame will have a pts, so I am guessing you will have to figure out the time near a frame, call those 0 frame and 0 time, then you will know that if you have a sample rate of 96000 samples/s then a frame at pts 96000 you are a second 1 (which you have somehow correlated to a real time)

Comment: @Brad no,  It is RTSP real time video frame from my live Camera.  Not a video file.  I

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps... this example uses the command line version to do a timestamp overlay; I'd bet the ffmpeg library has a way to do that somewhere... 
http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/

Comment: @Brad   I use Qt  QPaintor to do this.  Thank you.